# Add Back Button back into navigationController after adding custom button

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement a `navigationcontroller` that has a `uitableview` in it. This tableview should be editable, and to add rows to the table the user should press a plus button on the top bar on the screen. However, when I add a `uibarbuttonitem` and set it to the left side, the back button doesn't re-appear? how would i make it reappear?

The edit button:

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button];
```

The `editButtonPressed` method:

```
[_actionList setEditing:TRUE];
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAction)];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:addButton animated:TRUE];
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(editButtonDone)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:editButton animated:TRUE];
[self disableButtons];
```

The `editButtonDone` method:

```
[_actionList setEditing:FALSE];
editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editButtonPressed)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:editButton];
[self enableButtons];
```

I'm a beginner so sorry if this is dumb.

Comment: Try resetting left bar button when you leave edit mode. `[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];`

Comment: @Andy if you want the accepted answer, go ahead and submit your suggestion as one, it was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting left bar button when you leave edit mode.

```
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    [yourNavBar pushNavigationItem:self.navigationItem animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps